# Firebug 1.2 document.cookie inconsistency with Web Developer

Tags: javascript, firebug

I have a URI here in which a simple document.cookie query through the console is resulting in three cookies being displayed. I verified this with trivial code such as the following as well:

```
var cookies = document.cookie.split(';'); 
console.log(cookies.length);
```

The variable cookies does indeed come out to the number 3. Web Developer on the other hand is indicating that a grand total of 8 cookies are in use.

I'm slightly confused to believe which is inaccurate. I believe the best solution might involve just reiterating the code above without the influence of Firebug. However, I was wondering if someone might suggest a more clever alternative to decipher which tool is giving me the inaccurate information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One reason might be that the other 5 cookies are HTTPONLY:

> http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms533046.aspx
>
> If the HttpOnly attribute is included
>   in the response header, the cookie is
>   still sent when the user browses to a
>   Web site in the valid domain. The
>   cookie cannot be accessed through
>   script in Internet Explorer 6 SP1,
>   even by the Web site that set the
>   cookie in the first place. This means
>   that even if a cross-site scripting
>   bug exists, and the user is tricked
>   into clicking a link that exploits
>   this bug, Windows Internet Explorer
>   does not send the cookie to a third
>   party. The information is safe.

Firefox also respects this flag (as of v2.0.0.5).

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure the web developer toolbar shows cookies for domain and sub-domains.

So it will show cookies for

abc.xyz.com
xyz.com

whether you are on a page of either domain